# Can't write try-else without except in python

Tags: python

I want to write something shaped like this this except the invalid_task and work functions are of course written inline.

```
unfinished_tasks = 0
async def worker(task):
    nonlocal unfinished_tasks
    unfinished_tasks += 1
    try:
        if is_invalid(task):
            return None
        result = work(task)
        if is_error(result):
            raise Exception()
        return result
    else:
        unfinished_tasks -= 1
```

But you can't write just:

```
try:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

You need an `except` to write an `else` (try-else-finally also doesn't work). The use case for an `else` without an `except` is to run some code on a non exception exit of the block. There are a few ways to exit a block, like `return`, `break`, or reaching the end of one of the code paths inside it.

Should python allow try-else without except? Is there a better way to write this?

My current solution is:

```
try:
    ...
except None: 
    raise
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `try: finally:` here?

Comment: No, I don't want to reduce `unfinished_tasks` when I exit due to exceptions.

Comment: @AKX The ‘finally:’ block gets executed even if an exception is thrown. As the OP says, the ‘else:’ block will get executed only on non-exception exit of the ‘try’ block.

Comment: You could also use a context manager that looks at whether the context is being exited with an exception.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put `unfinished_tasks -= 1` immediately before the `return`? That way it won't be executed if there's an exception.

Comment: You can put the else-code at both returns. But I already had a bug where I forgot it next to `is_invalid`. It's better to have it in one place.

Comment: If a task is invalid ie `is_invalid(task)`, then do you want to decrement `unfinished_tasks`? Right now, your code won't do that. And I assume an invalid task _should NOT_ count as 'unfinished'. So invalid tasks _should_ also execute `unfinished_tasks -= 1`

Comment: Oh that's right. I made an error in my testing. `else` does not work for `return`, `break`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case specifically you can use:

```
unfinished_tasks = 0
async def worker(task):
    nonlocal unfinished_tasks
    try:
        if is_invalid(task):
            return None
        result = work(task)
        if is_error(result):
            raise Exception()
        return result
    except:
        unfinished_tasks += 1
```

For general cases `pass` can be used:

```
try:
    ...
except: 
    pass
else:
    ...
```

Comment: This is different in that it doesn't count running tasks as unfinished, but in this case I'm only looking at them once they are finished anyway.

Comment: Also don't pass exceptions!! Instead do what I already did at the end of my post.

Answer (score 1):

aneroid correctly pointed out that the code example does not work. The best way to do the thing that I've found is: (But the accepted answer works for me)

```
unfinished_tasks += 1
was_exception = False
try:
  ...
except:
  was_exception = True
  raise
finally:
  if not was_exception:
    unfinished_tasks -= 1
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is any better than the solution in your question, which is cleaner IMO: `try:
    ...
except None: 
    raise
else:
    ...`